# Header logo in Ionic project collapses on Android when tab changed

Tags: android, ionic-framework

This might be a bit hard to explain/replicate because it's a big project and I'm pretty new to Ionic, so I appreciate any help in advance.

Basically, the issue is the image in the header(That appears on every tab) shows left on EVERY OTHER tab click.
(This can be seen in the pictures -- I run ionic serve and view in chrome)

[This is the correct way the image should appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmYJF.png)

[This is what happens when switching between tabs, only EVERY OTHER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biGd1.png)

I've mass searched any references to the image in CSS and commented out any generated ionic code that has ANYTHING to do with animation, and still having the same issue.

One interesting thing I noticed can be seen in inspect element on chrome when changing tabs:

Before tab change:

```
<div class="title title-center header-item" style="left: 65px; right: 65px; transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate3d(-237.125px, 0px, 0px); opacity: 0;"></div>
```

After:

```
<div class="title title-center header-item" style="left: 65px; right: 65px; transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"></div>
```

I think the transform has SOMETHING to do with it, but can't figure out anywhere that ionic is animating the image or referencing anything to change the location of the image.

Again, this only happens on android and works perfect in IOS.